# Are typescript enums deprecated or legacy?

Tags: typescript, enums

I would like to know if I should not use enum.

It's stated [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/issues/476) that it's not deprecated.

But, it is deemed [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/issues/476) as semi-legacy.

I have also seen information that tree-shaking with tools such as rollup does not remove the enum.

Is the enum deprecated after all?
Is there any official statement on this topic?

Comment: No, but there are some who prefer to avoid them anyway

Comment: www.typescriptlang.org would probably be a better [reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#objects-vs-enums) to the current state of affairs than those "ancient" issues. Quoting: "In modern TypeScript, you may not need an enum when an object with `as const` could suffice"

Comment: I'm wondering how to put together an authoritative answer here. Enums aren't *deprecated* so much as they're an artifact from an earlier time. Nowadays there is a pretty strict design goal that TS will not add features that emit JS from non-JS syntax. If TS didn't already have `enum`, it wouldn't get it until a [proposal for it](//github.com/rbuckton/proposal-enum) is [presented](//github.com/tc39/proposals/issues/342) and reached stage 3 of the [TC39 process](//tc39.es/process-document/). Since they're there, they probably will be forever (unless some incompatible JS `enum` is introduced).

Comment: @jcalz it's a little tricky because I believe part of the reason they were introduced was to enable the language designers to implement the compiler in TypeScript with both readability and performance. At that time all the values were numeric.

Comment: Possible sources for answer: discussion in [ms/TS#35039](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35039), [ms/TS#41744](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41744), [ms/TS#45956](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45956),

Comment: Thank you all. I will keep this in mind for future reference.